# Wordpress form submission

Tags: forms, post, bootstrap-4

I am rebuilding a site for a client in Wordpress.  The form submission previously worked completely fine on a static site, but is not fully functioning in Wordpress.

In the back end php file in my theme I have:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php

$responseModal = "";
$error = "";

if ($_POST) {

    if (!$_POST["firstName"] || !$_POST["lastName"]) {

    $error .= "A first & last name is required.<br>";

    }

if (!$_POST["email"]) {

    $error .= "An email address is required.<br>";

}

if (!$_POST["phone"]) {

    $error .= "A phone number is required.<br>";

}

if (!$_POST["subject"]) {

    $error .= "An event description is required.<br>";

}

if (!$_POST["cateringType"]) {

    $error .= "You did not specify the type of catering for your 
event.<br>";

}

if ($error != "") {

    $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> . 
<strong>There were error(s) in your form:</strong><br>' . $error . 
'</div>';
    $responseModal = '<script type=\'text/javascript\'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(\'#errorModal\').modal(\'show\');
}); </script>';

} else {

    $emailTo = "foo@example.com";
    $subject = "New Event Request";
    $body = "Name: " . $_POST['firstName'] . " " . $_POST['lastName'] 
.
        "\nEmail: " . $_POST['email'] .
        "\nPhone: " . $_POST['phone'] .
        "\nDate: " . $_POST['month'] . "/" . $_POST['day'] . "/" . 
$_POST['year'] .
        "\nDescription: " . $_POST['subject'] .
        "\nLocation: " . $_POST['location'] .
        "\nCateringType: " . $_POST['cateringType'];
    $headers = "From: " . $_POST['email'];
    if (mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers)) {

        $responseModal = '<script type=\'text/javascript\'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(\'#successModal\').modal(\'show\');
}); </script>';

    } else {

        $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> . 
<strong>You message could not be delivered - please try again later. 
</strong></div>';
        $responseModal = '<script type=\'text/javascript\'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(\'#errorModal\').modal(\'show\');
}); </script>';

    }
}
}

?>

<?php //get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );  ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<? echo $responseModal; ?>

<!-- Success Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="successModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your 
message was sent, we'll get back to you ASAP!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data- 
   dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Error Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="errorModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <? echo $error ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Form Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="formModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Request Catering Info</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form method="post">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName">
                                    <small class="form-text text-muted">First Name</small>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName">
                                    <small class="form-text text-muted">Last Name</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cateringType">Which Type of Catering?</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="cateringType" name="cateringType">
                            <option></option>
                            <option>Option 1</option>
                            <option>Option 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="location">Where Is Your Event Located?</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="location" id="location">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="subject">Short Description of Event</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label>What's Your Event Date?
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="col-3">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="month" id="month">
                                            <small class="form-text text-muted">MM</small>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-3">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="day" id="day">
                                            <small class="form-text text-muted">DD</small>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="year" id="year">
                                            <small class="form-text text-muted">YYYY</small>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

In the page editor in Wordpress I have the code which launches the form modal (as well as other html which is irrelevant to this topic):

```
<!-- Button trigger form modal -->
    <div class="centerText">
        <h2>To contact us about catering
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModal">
                <h4 class="green">Click Here</h4>
            </button>
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

The page functions to the point that the form modal gets triggered, and  if the required fields are left blank, the error modal appears when the user attempts to submit.  If the form is filled out properly however, the success modal does not appear after submission and the email does not receive the message on the receiving end.  Also, the page content disappears and all you see is the theme template after this failed submission.  It doesn't make sense to me that the error code is working properly but it only breaks when an actual submission should be made.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change:

```
<form method="post">
```

to:

```
<form role="form" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
```

If this doesn't work on your modal, try on a normal page template. Let me know.